# Error while installing SSDT on Visual Studio 2017

Tags: sql-server, ssis, visual-studio-2017, sql-server-data-tools

I tried to install the SSDT (standalone) on my VS 2017 instance. But the installation did not continue until the end. I got an error (I will try to post the log file content below).

After that when I launch VS and try to create a new project, I find project templates for Analysis services but nothing for Integration services, it is like the installation was done partially !

When I try to reinstall SSDT it offers me only the option to install SSDT for a new instance of Visual Studio. The option I need  to install it on the already installed instance of Visual Studio is not here (yet it was there in the first attempt to install).

When I try to uninstall this "partial" installation of SSDT using the command: SSDT-Setup-FRA.exe /uninstall (hence my bad english :) The installer continue as if it was an installation !! Seems like the /uninstall is not taken into account !

So please What can I do to remove the "partial installation" or to launch a new installation for my existing instance of Visual Studio 2017 ?
And What can I do to avoid getting the same error I got with the first installation. Here is the last part of the content of the installation log file:

2021-09-29 18:11:46 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.Ancmv2.IISExpress.Msi,version=12.2.18292,chip=x64' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:46 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.SQL.DataSources,version=15.0.26621.2' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:46 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.DevOps,version=0.4.195.52948' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:46 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.Web.LibraryManager,version=1.0.151.20037' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:46 - Skipping cache of package 'Component.Microsoft.Web.LibraryManager,version=15.8.27705.0' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:46 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.Web,version=15.9.28219.51' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:46 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Mvc.Common,version=15.0.61435.0' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:46 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Mvc.Resources,version=15.0.61435.0,chip=neutral,language=fr-FR' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:46 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Mvc,version=15.0.61435.0' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:46 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.PackageGroup.WebStackRuntime,version=15.0.26504.0' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:46 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Package.DockerTools,version=1.1.20190319.4' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:46 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Package.DockerTools.BuildTools,version=1.1.20190319.4' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:46 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.DockerTools.BuildTools,version=15.7.27617.1' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:46 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Package.ContainersTools,version=1.1.1903.1901' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:46 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.DockerTools,version=15.8.27906.1' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:46 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Web,version=15.8.27825.0' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:46 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Wcf.Tooling,version=15.8.27924.0' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:47 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Graphics.Appid.Resources,version=15.8.27729.1,language=fr-FR' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:47 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Graphics.Appid,version=15.9.28307.473' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:47 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Graphics.Analyzer.Resources,version=15.9.28307.616,language=fr-FR' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:47 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Graphics.Analyzer.Targeted,version=15.0.26621.2,chip=x64' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:47 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Graphics.Analyzer,version=15.9.28016.0' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:47 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Graphics.Msi,version=15.8.27729.1,chip=x86' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:47 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Graphics.Msi,version=15.8.27729.1,chip=x64' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:47 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Graphics.EnableTools,version=15.8.27729.1' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:47 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Graphics.Win81,version=15.6.27406.0' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:47 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Graphics.Tools,version=15.6.27406.0' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:47 - Skipping cache of package 'Win10SDK_10.0.14393.795,version=10.0.14393.79518' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:47 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.14393,version=15.6.27406.0' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:47 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.UWP.NetCoreAndStandard,version=15.8.27906.1' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:47 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.AppAnalysis.Resources,version=15.9.28107.0,language=fr-FR' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:47 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.AppAnalysis.Targeted,version=15.9.28107.0,chip=x64' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:47 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.AppAnalysis,version=15.9.28107.0' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:47 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.PackageGroup.UWP.ClientDiagnostics,version=15.0.26208.0' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:48 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesktopBridge.Tools.Resources,version=15.9.28218.60,language=fr-FR' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:48 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesktopBridge.Tools,version=15.9.28218.60' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:48 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.VisualCpp.CRT.Appx.ARM64.Msi,version=14.16.27023' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:48 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.UWP.Support,version=15.9.28119.51' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:48 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Universal,version=15.9.28307.102' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:48 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Templates.CS.ManagedWeb.Shared,version=15.7.27604.0' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:48 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Templates.GetStarted.Web.Setup,version=15.8.0.6311901' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:48 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Templates.CS.GettingStarted.Web.Package,version=15.8.27924.0' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:48 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.WebToolsExtensions.DotNet.ItemTemplates,version=15.9.40053.24908' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:48 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.WebToolsExtensions.DotNet.ProjectTemplates.Resources,version=15.9.40053.24908,chip=neutral,language=fr-FR' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:48 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.WebToolsExtensions.DotNet.ProjectTemplates,version=15.9.40053.24908' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:48 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.NetCore.FSharp.ProjectTemplates.Web,version=2.9.0.6402904' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:48 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.FSharp.WebTemplates,version=15.9.28307.421' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:48 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.NetCore.ComponentGroup.Web.2.1,version=15.8.27924.0' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:48 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.KeychainCredentialHelper,version=15.9.81.48455' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:48 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.AzureFunctions,version=15.10.2059.23219' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:48 - Skipping cache of package 'Component.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.AzureFunctions,version=15.7.27617.1' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:48 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.AzureFunctions,version=15.7.27617.1' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:48 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.CloudExplorer,version=1.2.1810.253' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:48 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Waverton.Resources,version=2.9.90417.1,language=fr-FR' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:48 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Waverton,version=2.9.90417.1' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:48 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.Azure.Compute.Emulator.Exe,version=2.9.8899.26,chip=x64' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:48 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Azure.Compute.Emulator,version=15.9.28307.421' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:48 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Emulator.Msi,version=5.7.0' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:48 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Azure.Storage.Emulator,version=15.9.28125.51' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:48 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.Azure.ClientLibs.Msi,version=3.0.127.62,chip=x64' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:48 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Azure.ClientLibs,version=15.0.26208.0' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:48 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.Azure.AuthoringTools.Msi,version=2.9.8899.26,chip=x64' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:48 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Azure.AuthoringTools,version=15.9.28307.421' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:48 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CloudExplorer,version=15.9.28230.55' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:48 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.NetCore.ComponentGroup.Web,version=15.7.27625.0' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:48 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetWeb,version=15.8.27906.1' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:48 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.Component.NetFX.Core.Runtime,version=15.0.26208.0' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:48 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.Azure.Prerequisites,version=15.9.28107.0' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:48 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.Azure.DataLake.Tools.VisualStudio.Extension,version=2.3.3000.2' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:48 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.Azure.DataLake.Tools.SDK.Compiler,version=10.0.10240.3,chip=neutral' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:48 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Waverton.Projects.Resources,version=2.9.90417.1,language=fr-FR' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:48 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Waverton.Projects,version=2.9.90417.1' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:48 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Waverton.BuildTools,version=2.9.90417.1' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:48 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Azure.Waverton.BuildTools,version=15.7.27617.1' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:48 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Azure.Waverton,version=15.9.28107.0' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:48 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.Component.Azure.DataLake.Tools,version=15.9.28107.0' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:48 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.Azure.PowerShellNew,version=15.7.27617.1,chip=x64' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:48 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.ResourceManager.Tools,version=3.0.90205.1' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:48 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Azure.ResourceManager.Tools,version=15.9.28107.0' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:48 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.Azure.ResourceManager.Tools,version=15.0.27005.2' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:48 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.Azure.CloudServices,version=15.0.26504.0' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:48 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.Azure.MobileAppsSdkPackages.Msi,version=15.0.27005.2' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:48 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.Azure.MobileAppsSdkTemplates.Vsix,version=15.0.26504.0' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:48 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Azure.MobileAppsSdk,version=15.7.27625.0' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:48 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Package.Azure.ServiceFabric.Tools,version=2.5.20190608.1' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:48 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Azure.ServiceFabric.Tools,version=15.8.27825.0' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:48 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Azure,version=15.8.27906.1' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:49 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.OfficeDeveloperTools.Msi,version=15.0.27005.2' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:49 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.OfficeDeveloperTools.Resources,version=15.9.28230.55,language=fr-FR' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:49 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.OfficeDeveloperTools,version=15.9.28230.55' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:49 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.PackageGroup.OfficeDeveloperTools,version=15.7.27520.0' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:49 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.OfficeDeveloperTools.BuildTools.Resources,version=15.8.27924.0,language=fr-FR' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:49 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.OfficeDeveloperTools.BuildTools,version=15.8.27924.0' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:49 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.OfficeDeveloperTools.MicrosoftIdentityExtensions.Msi,version=15.0.27205.0,chip=x64' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:49 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.OfficeDeveloperTools.WIF.WindowsFeature,version=15.8.27729.1' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:49 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.PackageGroup.Sharepoint.Runtime,version=15.0.26208.0' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:49 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.OfficeDeveloperTools.OpenXMLSDK.Msi,version=15.0.27005.2' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:49 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.OfficeDeveloperTools.ExchangeWebServices.Msi,version=15.0.27005.2' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:49 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.WorkflowV2,version=15.9.28128.56' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:49 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.WorkflowV2.Resources,version=15.9.28107.0,language=fr-FR' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:49 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.PackageGroup.WorkflowV2.BuildTools,version=15.8.27825.0' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:49 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.WorkflowV2.Debugger.Msi,version=15.0.27005.2,chip=x64' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:49 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.PackageGroup.WorkflowV2,version=15.8.27825.0' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:49 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Workflow,version=15.8.27825.0' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:49 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.WorkflowV1,version=15.9.28307.753' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:49 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.WorkflowV1.Resources,version=15.9.28307.753,language=fr-FR' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:49 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.WorkflowV1.Debugger.Msi,version=15.0.27005.2,chip=x86' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:49 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.WorkflowV1.Debugger.Msi,version=15.0.27005.2,chip=x64' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:49 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.PackageGroup.WorkflowV1,version=15.8.27825.0' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:49 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.WorkflowManagerClient.Msi,version=15.0.26621.2,chip=x64,language=fr-FR' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:49 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.WorkflowManagerTools.Msi,version=15.6.27323.2,chip=x64,language=fr-FR' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:49 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.WorkflowManagerTools.Resources,version=15.0.26504.0,language=fr-FR' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:49 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.WorkflowManagerTools,version=15.8.27729.1' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:49 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.PackageGroup.Workflow.ManagerTools,version=15.8.27825.0' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:49 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Sharepoint.Tools,version=15.8.27924.0' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:49 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Vsto.Resources,version=15.8.27924.0,language=fr-FR' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:49 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Vsto,version=15.8.27924.0' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:49 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Vsto.Msi.Resources,version=15.8.27729.1,language=fr-FR' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:49 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Vsto.Msi.x64,version=15.8.27729.1,chip=x64' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:49 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Vsto.Msi,version=15.8.27729.1' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:49 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.PackageGroup.Vsto,version=15.7.27520.0' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:49 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Vsto.BuildTools.Resources,version=15.8.27825.0,language=fr-FR' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:49 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Vsto.BuildTools,version=15.8.27825.0' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:49 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Vsto.Runtime,version=15.0.26621.2,chip=x64' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:49 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Vsto.Runtime.Resources,version=15.0.26621.2,chip=x64,language=fr-FR' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:49 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.PackageGroup.Vsto.Runtime,version=15.0.26208.0' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:49 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.TeamOffice,version=15.7.27625.0' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:11:49 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Office,version=15.8.27924.0' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:18:04 - Skipping cache of package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetCoreTools,version=15.8.27906.1' since the package or a parent package had a vital failure.
2021-09-29 18:23:48 - END: SetupEngine Install
2021-09-29 18:23:48 - END: Execute batch install
2021-09-29 18:23:48 - END: Targetting Visual Studio Community 2017,15.0.28307.770
2021-09-29 18:23:48 - END: Installing
2021-09-29 18:23:48 - END: Batch install using SetupEngine
2021-09-29 18:23:48 - System.AggregateException: Une ou plusieurs erreurs se sont produites. ---> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.PackageFailureException: Package 'Microsoft.Net.Core.SDK.2.1' failed to install
à Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.InstallOperation.Run(CancellationToken token)
à Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Engine.RunOperation(InstallOperation installOperation, CancellationToken token, ExecuteAction action, ITelemetryOperation telemetryOperation)
à Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Engine.RunCoreOperation(InstallOperation coreOperation, ExecuteAction action, ITelemetryOperation telemetryOperation, CancellationToken token)
à Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Engine.Install(Product product, String destination, CancellationToken token)
à Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.SetupEngineService.b__14_0()
à System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke() à System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute() --- Fin de la trace de la pile à partir de l'emplacement précédent au niveau duquel l'exception a été levée --- à Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.WindowsErrorReporting.WatsonReport.GetClrWatsonExceptionInfo(Exception exceptionObject) --- Fin de la trace de la pile d'exception interne --- à System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions) à System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken) à Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.SetupEngineService.Install() à Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.ExtensionBatchEngine.Execute(List`1 installableExtensions, Version targetVsVersion)
à Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.ExtensionEngineImpl.BatchEngineInstall(List`1 installableExtensions, InstallFlags installFlags, Version targetVsVersion) à VSIXInstaller.BatchSetupEngineInstaller.Install(SupportedVSSKU sku, List`1 extensionsToInstall, InstallFlags installFlags)
à VSIXInstaller.BatchSetupEngineInstaller.BatchInstall(IReadOnlyList`1 targetSkus, IEnumerable`1 extensionsToInstall)
à VSIXInstaller.SilentEngine.Execute(ExtensionData data)
à VSIXInstaller.App.OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
---> (Exception interne #0) Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.PackageFailureException: Package 'Microsoft.Net.Core.SDK.2.1' failed to install
à Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.InstallOperation.Run(CancellationToken token)
à Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Engine.RunOperation(InstallOperation installOperation, CancellationToken token, ExecuteAction action, ITelemetryOperation telemetryOperation)
à Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Engine.RunCoreOperation(InstallOperation coreOperation, ExecuteAction action, ITelemetryOperation telemetryOperation, CancellationToken token)
à Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Engine.Install(Product product, String destination, CancellationToken token)
à Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.SetupEngineService.b__14_0()
à System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
à System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- Fin de la trace de la pile à partir de l'emplacement précédent au niveau duquel l'exception a été levée ---
à Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.WindowsErrorReporting.WatsonReport.GetClrWatsonExceptionInfo(Exception exceptionObject)

Comment: It's been a *long* time since I installed the products for VS2017 (4~ years probably) but I *think* they were separate installs. They certainly are in 2019; speaking of which why *not* use VS 2019?

Comment: I remember something like this happening to me.  In my case, SSIS was installed, but the templates were not showing up in the search menu.  Can you try to open an existing SSIS project and see if it is able to load?

Comment: @larnu VS2017 is a client requirement

Comment: @MarkWojciechowicz VS doesn't recognize SSIS projects (*.dtproj)

Comment: Then, presumably, when you used the [standalone installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-ver15#install-analysis-services-integration-services-and-reporting-services-tools) you didn't chose integration services to be installed, @DadyFuji .

Comment: @Larnu Yes I did choose it, but the installation failed in the middle of the process, so it was like done partially.

Comment: Have you tried restarting between your attempts? VS often needs these.

Comment: @Larnu yes no more success !

Comment: Are there any errors above what you've posted in the file?  It starts with `since the package or a parent package had a vital failure` which suggests something has already gone wrong

Comment: @MarkWojciechowicz this is because the limitation in the size of the question. I found this in the log file, though it is the main error who makes the install failed. 2021-09-29 18:11:45 - Package 'Microsoft.Net.Core.SDK.2.1,version=15.9.28307.769,chip=x64' failed to install. , Details: Une autre version de ce produit est déjà installée. Signature: PackageId=Microsoft.Net.Core.SDK.2.1;PackageAction=install;ReturnCode=1638

Comment: Can you see if another version of `Microsoft .Net Core SDK 2.1` shows up in programs and features?  If so, can you uninstall it?